# In machine learning, why do we say "curve fitting" when really fit the hypersurface?

Tags: machine-learning, curve-fitting

**Curve** and **surface** are distinct concepts yet they seem to be used interchangeably in the context of model fitting.

For a single argument function f(x) the concept of curve fitting is clear. The function defines a curve. So function fitting is curve fitting.

However, for a function with multiple arguments f(x1, x2, x3, ...) that we expect to be defined for all domain values (as it is the case in machine learning), I can't see how a curve could do. My understanding is we really fit a hypersurface yet we still say "fitting the curve".

Example from "Deep Learning with Python" book:

> [...] deep learning is about taking a big, complex curve - a manifold - and incrementally adjusting its parameters until it fits some training data points.

But then again, manifold is a type of (hyper)surface (in >1D) and curve is a curve. What's going on here?

Comment: I think the term "curve" there is used a bit loosely. In general, for many features, we ML we try to build surfaces, though through marginal effects then we can get "curves".

Comment: The (hyper-)surface is curved and so the meaning of a univariate "curve"  is extended to this.

Comment: To mathematicians, curves and surfaces are pretty much the same thing, or more precisely, curves are just special cases (codimension 1) of the more general concept of a manifold (or nonsmooth generalizations of manifolds).

Comment: Machine learning accounts of mathematical concepts tend to be sloppy.  This is one example.